# Low-level bit shift register class using port manipulation for Arduino Zero

Tags: c++, arduino, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, samd21

I'm currently trying to code a lower-lever bit shift register (74HC595) for Arduino Zero (that is based on SAMD21 Cortex M0).

I've already done a higher-level class with looks like that :

BitRegister.h

```
#ifndef BitRegister_h
#define BitRegister_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class BitRegister
{
  public:
    BitRegister(byte dataPin, byte clockPin, byte latchPin, uint8_t registerSize = 1);
    
    void sendData(uint8_t led);
    void shiftOut2(uint8_t bitOrder, uint8_t val);

  private:
    byte m_dataPin;
    byte m_clockPin;
    byte m_latchPin;
    uint8_t m_registerSize; //allows register's cascade
};

#endif
```

BitRegister.cpp

```
#include "BitRegister.h"

//**************************************************************
  
BitRegister::BitRegister(byte dataPin, 
                        byte clockPin, 
                        byte latchPin,
                        uint8_t registerSize)
:   m_dataPin(dataPin),
    m_clockPin(clockPin),
    m_latchPin(latchPin),
    m_registerSize(registerSize) //Number of register (if cascade)
{
  pinMode(m_dataPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(m_clockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(m_latchPin, OUTPUT);
}

//************************************************************** 

void BitRegister::sendData(uint8_t led)
{
  led -= 1; //first LED is number 1

  digitalWrite(m_latchPin, LOW);
  for(int i = 1; i < m_registerSize + 1; i++){
    int registerNumber = m_registerSize - i; //The number of the register we're working on in the loop
    shiftOut(m_dataPin, m_clockPin, MSBFIRST, ~( 1 << (led - registerNumber*8) ) & 0xFF);
  }

  digitalWrite(m_latchPin, HIGH);
}

void BitRegister::shiftOut2(uint8_t bitOrder, uint8_t val)
{
    uint8_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)  {
        if (bitOrder == LSBFIRST)
            digitalWrite(m_dataPin, !!(val & (1 << i)));
        else    
            digitalWrite(m_dataPin, !!(val & (1 << (7 - i))));

        digitalWrite(m_clockPin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(m_clockPin, LOW);        
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have to use it with many registers in cascade ant the `shiftOut2` method (based on Arduino's  `shiftOut` method) is really slow (I think due to the multiple `digitalWrite`).

So based on this [SAMD21 Cortex M0 tutorial](https://community.atmel.com/sites/default/files/forum_attachments/PIN-IO-SAMD21-SAMR21_RevA_0.pdf) and on the Arduino Zero Pinout Diagram (below), I tried to create a lower-level of my bit shift register class. [image: Arduino Zero Pinout Diagram]

The problem I'm currently facing is that I don't manage to rewrite the totality of my `shiftOut2` method so for my test I have to write the ports numbers in hard directly in the method's body.

I connect my registers to Arduino's pins 10, 11 and 12 which are SAMD21 ports 18, 16 and 19.

The code of my class (which works) is the following :

`LowBitRegister.h` is the same as `BitRegister.h` (except class name and class constructor name).

LowBitRegister.cpp

```
#include "LowBitRegister.h"

//**************************************************************  

LowBitRegister::LowBitRegister(byte dataPin, 
                        byte clockPin, 
                        byte latchPin,
                        uint8_t registerSize)
:   m_dataPin(dataPin),
    m_clockPin(clockPin),
    m_latchPin(latchPin),
    m_registerSize(registerSize) //Number of register (if cascade)
{
  REG_PORT_DIR0 |= (1 << 18) | (1 << 19) | (1 << 16); //Set dataPin, clockPin and latchPin to OUTPUT
}

//************************************************************** 

void LowBitRegister::sendData(uint8_t led)
{
  led -= 1; //first LED is number 1
  
  REG_PORT_OUT0 &= ~(1 << 16); //Set latchPin to LOW
  
  for(int i = 1; i < m_registerSize + 1; i++){
    int registerNumber = m_registerSize - i; //The number of the register we're working on in the loop
    shiftOut2(MSBFIRST, ~( 1 << (led - registerNumber*8) ) & 0xFF);
  }
  
  REG_PORT_OUT0 |= (1 << 16); //Set latchPin to HIGH
}

void LowBitRegister::shiftOut2(uint8_t bitOrder, uint8_t val)
{
  uint8_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)  {
    if (bitOrder == LSBFIRST)
      digitalWrite(m_dataPin, !!(val & (1 << i)));
    else    
      digitalWrite(m_dataPin, !!(val & (1 << (7 - i))));

    REG_PORT_OUT0 |= (1 << 19); //Set clockPin to HIGH
    REG_PORT_OUT0 &= ~(1 << 19); //Set clockPin to LOW     
  }
}
```

As you can see, the only parts I don't manage to rewrite are :

```
digitalWrite(m_dataPin, !!(val & (1 << i)));
```

and

```
digitalWrite(m_dataPin, !!(val & (1 << (7 - i))));
```

If you have an idea to solve my problem I will be happy to read it.

Thank you!

Comment: I have never heard of a register waterfall. do you mean a cascade?  `!!(val & (1 << i))` why the double negation of your values? what's the point of that? just use the value as is.  why is this named shiftOut2? I would expect 2 things to be shifted if I read such a name without any comment. so you cannot set the clock pin in your second snippet? I cannot follow you. you have two snippets with the same file name. which one is which?

Comment: Sorry, I'm indeed talking about cascade. The double negation I to convert any non-zero value to one (I could keep the value as is). The ```shiftOut2``` makes the same as ```shiftOut```it's true that I could change the name. It was to have the possibility tu use normal ```shiftOut``` and my custom ```shiftOut2``` without making mistakes. The ```BitRegister``` is my former register class. The class I currently use is ```LowBitregister```(I edited it in my question). The problem is that I don't know how to rewrite ```digitalWrite(m_dataPin, !!(val & (1 << i)))``` using port manipulation syntax.

Comment: well you need to map the pin numbers to a port register. or just stick with the Arduino way. using hardware registers kind of defies the purpose of Arduino. everything is kept board independant. your MCU does not matter as long as you use digitalWrite.

Comment: I think we misunderstood each other. My goal is to get rid of ```digitalWrite```. I finally found the solution (which is actually not that complicated but if you see any optimization I am interested).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution (but if you see any optimization I am interested) :

LowBitRegister.h

```
#ifndef LowBitRegister_h
#define LowBitRegister_h

#include "Arduino.h"


class LowBitRegister
{
  public:
    LowBitRegister(byte dataPin, byte clockPin, byte latchPin, uint8_t registerSize = 1); //Multiple registers cascade
    
    void sendData(uint8_t led);
    void lowShiftOut(uint8_t bitOrder, uint8_t val);

  private:
    byte m_dataPin;
    byte m_clockPin;
    byte m_latchPin;
    uint8_t m_registerSize;
};

#endif
```

LowBitRegister.cpp

```
#include "LowBitRegister.h"

//**************************************************************  

LowBitRegister::LowBitRegister(byte dataPin, 
                        byte clockPin, 
                        byte latchPin,
                        uint8_t registerSize)
:   m_dataPin(dataPin),
    m_clockPin(clockPin),
    m_latchPin(latchPin),
    m_registerSize(registerSize) //Number of register (if cascade)
{
  REG_PORT_DIR0 |= (1 << m_dataPin) | (1 << m_clockPin) | (1 << m_latchPin); //Set dataPin, clockPin and latchPin to OUTPUT
}

//************************************************************** 

void LowBitRegister::sendData(uint8_t led)
{
  led -= 1; //first LED is number 1
  
  REG_PORT_OUT0 &= ~(1 << m_latchPin); //Set latchPin to LOW
  
  for(int i = 1; i < m_registerSize + 1; i++){
    int registerNumber = m_registerSize - i; //The number of the register we're working on in the loop
    lowShiftOut(MSBFIRST, ~( 1 << (led - registerNumber*8) ) & 0xFF);
  }
  
  REG_PORT_OUT0 |= (1 << m_latchPin); //Set latchPin to HIGH
}

void LowBitRegister::lowShiftOut(uint8_t bitOrder, uint8_t val)
{
  uint8_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (bitOrder == LSBFIRST){
      if(val & (1 << i))
        REG_PORT_OUT0 |= (1 << m_dataPin);
      else
        REG_PORT_OUT0 &= ~(1 << m_dataPin);
    }
    else {
      if (val & (1 << (7 - i)))
        REG_PORT_OUT0 |= (1 << m_dataPin);
      else
        REG_PORT_OUT0 &= ~(1 << m_dataPin);
    }
    REG_PORT_OUT0 |= (1 << m_clockPin); //Set clockPin to HIGH
    REG_PORT_OUT0 &= ~(1 << m_clockPin); //Set clockPin to LOW     
  }
}
```